# Entities created with new

Tags: php, doctrine, doctrine-orm

In the Doctrine Getting Started tutorial, there is an example of a bug creation.  A bug has a reporter and an engineer property of entity User.

The example has you passing an id of an existing reporter and an existing engineer.   The example then uses the id to find the User in the database.

```
$reporter = $entityManager->find("User", $theReporterId);
$engineer = $entityManager->find("User", $theDefaultEngineerId);
```

Later, the reporter and engineer is attached to the bug.

```
$bug->setReporter($reporter);
$bug->setEngineer($engineer);
```

Since I know the id, I thought I would be clever and create a new User, set the id to the passed variable and call persist on the users.

```
$reporter = new User();
$reporter->setId($theReporterId);
$reporter->setName("Foo");
$entityManager->persist($reporter);
```

I then continue with the call setReporter/Engineer with the new User objects, call persist on the bug, then call flush.

However, when this happens, a new user is created for the reporter and engineer, and the bug's entry in the db is set to the new ids of the new users.

It looks like Doctrine doesn't know that the new User is based on existing entities.  Is there a way I can do what I want to do?  I figure this would be a good way to bypass the hit to the database to get a user.

Comment: If User is an entity why do you duplicate the reporter? I mean, it's an entity - you shouldn't even be able to add another entity with the same ID.

Comment: Why do you create a new user if you know its id? You could load it. Also, to avoid duplicated creations, call the `flush()` before of reporter and engineer setters

Comment: > Why do you create a new user if you know its id? You could load it.

That's kind of the question I had.  Let's say there is a bug reporting form.  The reporter field is a dropdown of all the Users.  The user id is passed to the server.

I now have the user id that I want to attach to the bug. If I load the user using the id, isn't that an unnecessary database call?

Comment: No, it is not a problem. This is the way how doctrine works (entity relationships)